# Selenium - clicking on youtube links

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I just tried to open the first search result of the youtube link. 
Here is my code. Since the youtube results are in iFrame, I used SwitchTo.frame()method.

```
   String browser = "Chrome";
    WebDriver b =  null;
    if(browser.equals("Chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        b = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if (browser.equals("firefox")) {

        b = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    b.get("http://www.youtube.com/");
    b.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='masthead-search-term']")).sendKeys("selenium tutorial for beginner");
    b.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='masthead-search-term']")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    b.switchTo().frame("pyv-iframe"); //youtube search results are in iframe
    //b.findElement(By.linkText("Selenium IDE Demo - Quick Beginner's Tutorial")).click();
    b.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='search-results']/li[1]/div[2]/h3/a/span")).click();
```

While running this code it returns as

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
```

at findElement By xpath. Please tell me what am I missing. Please see me as a newbie to Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are saying that the results are in an `<iframe>`... I'm not seeing an iframe.  Here is your script using the [getting started with selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) framework:

```
@Config(url="http://youtube.com")
public class YouTubeTest extends AutomationTest {
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        setText(By.id("masthead-search-term"), "selenium tutorial for beginner")
        .click(By.id("search-btn"))

        // navigate to a search result based on index
        .click(By.cssSelector("ol#search-results > li:nth-child(X) a.yt-uix-tile-link"))
        ;
    }
}
```

on the `click(By.cssSelector` you need to replace the `X` value with `1`, `2`, etc.. whatever the index of the link you want to click is.

(If you aren't using that framework you can easily translate the code and extract the selectors I use)

Answer (score 0):

I did investigate on the Youtube page in [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) and it did get me these results:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl + "/results?search_query=selenium&sm=3");
driver.findElement(By.id("masthead-search-term")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("masthead-search-term")).sendKeys("selenium");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.yt-ui-ellipsis-wrapper")).click();
```

Please note the last line: Thats where I clicked on the first search result. After investigating the Youtube page with Web [Developer tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) I realised that here is a `iframe` but it contains  only some tracking code for AdSense (my guess)

General note: Always try to investigate with Selenium IDE first. It saved me from a lots of nightmares about my selenium code ;)